# How to Plot data from Beginning

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, flot

I want to develop a dynamic page that is connected to MySQL database (from a server) and display the result in a plot in real time. So far I managed to get my data from my database and display the graph. However, I couldn't manage to do it in real time.

I have a database table named test and have 2 columns. 'id' and 'age'

```
id age

1 45

2 41

3 09

......

60 11
```

I want to fetch data from database one by one and plot it in the chart, i mean at first fetch 45 and plot it in the chart and then again fetch 41 and add it in the chart with 45 and so on... and then when new data point will come, old data will shift.It will continue until it complete fetching.

```
<?php
include("md.php");
$arr = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);

$con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','user2','123','test');
$select="select age from tab";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $select);
$i=0;                      
while ($row=$res->fetch_assoc()) {
$arr=array_slice($arr,1,8);
$arr[]=array($i++, (int)$row['age']);
echo json_encode($arr)."<br>";
}  
?>
```

I'm getting output as follows=

```
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11]]

[0,0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11],[3,21]]

[0,0,0,0,0,[0,45],[1,41],[2,11],[3,21],[4,44]]

.............................
[[1,41],[2,11],[3,21],[4,44],[5,13],[6,15],[7,12],[8,7],[9,14],[10,11]]

........................
[[41,4],[42,11],[43,1],[44,54],[45,13],[46,15],[47,2],[48,7],[49,14],[50,61]]
```

then when i'm plotting data, its taking only last 10 values. I want to get data in chart from beginning one by one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var data=[];
function f(){
data= <?php echo json_encode($arr) ?>;
}

var options={
                series: {
                        lines: {
                                show: true,
                                lineWidth: 2,

                                },
                        points:{
                                show: true
                                }
                        },
             };
$(document).ready(function () {
f();
var dataset=[
              { 
                label: "Data", 
                data: data, 
                points: { 
                            symbol: true
                        } 
             }
            ];

     $.plot($("#flot-container"), dataset , options);
function update() {
f();
data.shift();


$.plot($("#flot-container"), dataset, options);
setTimeout(update, 5000);
      }
      update();
});

</script>
```

I want the output [**AS**](http://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Real-time_graphing)

How can i execute it?Where am i doing wrong?please help.

Comment: First of all i realy don't get what you want to achive? Do you want to get the data from DB as 2 dimension array? like 
`array(
    array('id' => 1, 'age' => 45),
    array('id' => 2, 'age' => 41),
    ...
)`

Comment: @Santa'shelper As you can see that while fetching data at first [0,45] is inserted and then in next row [1,41] is inserted. i just to see those data in the chart like real-time chart.